# 22.04 LTS unable to print to “HP Neverstop Laser MFP 1202w” printer

Tags: networking, drivers, hp

Newly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a dual boot PC. It won’t print to the network attached “HP Neverstop Laser MFP 1202w” printer (Note: the printer works well with another PC running Ubuntu 20.04.4).

1. Ubuntu is aware of the printer.
2. I used the GUI Settings interface to select various drivers via “Select from database...”. Outcome varies but never with a successful print.
3. This is the last two lines from the Cups error_log:

E [07/Jun/2022:15:39:36 -0700] [Job 48] No destination host name supplied by cups-browsed for printer "HP_Neverstop_Laser_MFP_1202w_FDF30F@NPIFDF30F.local", is cups-browsed running?

W [07/Jun/2022:15:39:36 -0700] [Job 48] Backend returned status 4 (stop printer)

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Via System Monitor, I do not see it running.

Comment: Cups-browsed is running.

Comment: Access the CUPS UI by browsing to `http://localhost:631`. Add your printer through the `Admin` tab.

Comment: Thank you waltinator, you gave me a start point. I now have a source for learning about CUPS.

Comment: Well, that went quick! The printer is now printing. Again, thank you waltinator for your guidance.